# Joomla - перенос на другой хостинг

Tags: joomla, php

Перенёс сайт на другой хостинг, скопировал БД, сам сайт, всё как положено. Админка работает отлично, а вот при заходе на главную страничку пишет "404 - компонент не найден", я даже не знаю что делать, подскажите пож-та.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, решил проблему, это всё из-за операционки хостинга, у windows не `.htacces`, а `IIS`.

Answer (score 0):

А домен вы случайно не меняли? Просто в Jooml'e записывается при установке домен, который в дальнейшем используется как переменная. Пересмотрите вашу конфигурацию в Joomla.

Comment: Нет, не менял